# Definition of an $r$-permutation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to understand the definition of an $r$-permutation. Suppose you have $7$ aligned seats and $7$ distinct people, there are $7!$ different ways of seating them.

Suppose that I am trying to seat $7$ distinct people in $9$ seats, is that when I use the formula $P(n,r)=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$?

My thinking is there are two same seats (empty), so the number of distinguishable permutations is $9!/2!$ which is that formula above. So my question is, is $r$-permutation a method to figure out the permutation of $r$ objects in $n$ boxes when $n \ge k$?

*Follow up if you have time:* If the seats formed a circle, we would divide by $7$ as the seatings are equivalent up to rotation correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By r-permutation, I think u mean $P_r^n$.
You need to understand the concept behind using a formula instead of blindly applying it.
In your example, there are 9 seats and 7 people, so the total number of seating people is indeed $\frac {9!}{2!}$. You can think of it this way. For the first person, there are 9 possible seats on which he can sit. For the second person, there are 8 seats left, then there are 7 for the third and so on. The last or the seventh person will have 3 seats to choose from. Following this logic, the number of ways the people can sit is $9*8*7*6*5*4*3= \frac {9!}{2!}$. Thus, you get your required answer. This can now be generalised to r people and n seats with $n>r$. So the first has n seats to choose from, second has (n-1), third has (n-2)... until the last person(r) has (n-r+1) seats on which he can sit. So the total number of ways is $n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+1)$ which can be expressed as $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$. Hence, an r-permutation is a method to seat r people in n seats or permute r objects in n boxes where $n>r$.

For your follow up question, we would divide by 7 if the order of the seats does not matter and the seats are not numbered.

Comment: You would divide by $7!$ in the final case, not by $7$.

Comment: I think we would divide by 7 and not 7! as the total number of permutations itself is 7! for 7 seats and $\frac{9!}{2!}$ for 9 seats. If we divide by 7! we would get 1 in the first case and 36 in second case. This answer seems unreasonable

Comment: No, it’s not unreasonable. If the order of the chairs does not matter, that means the chairs are indistinguishable and you don’t care who sits where. Then your only task is to select the two chairs that nobody is sitting on... but the chairs cannot be distinguished! So the only thing you need to do is take two chairs (any two chairs) out of the room; there is one and only one way of doing that. Saying the order of the seats does not matter is not the same as counting circular arrangements. You are describing a different problem, even if you are trying to solve the stated one.

Comment: Oh I understand. Your answer does make sense in selecting any 2 unwanted chairs, but what I meant to say was about the circular rotations/arrangements.Sorry for not being specific.